# Get SPL Token Holders

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, spl-token

Is there any other method to retrieve SPL token holders?

I'm currently using the Helius API, but it's giving me an **"exceeded limit"** error.

Answer (score 1):

To preface, I am an employee at Helius.

The [DAS API](https://docs.helius.dev/compression-and-das-api/digital-asset-standard-das-api) only returns up to 1000 records at a time. If you need to retrieve more than 1000 items, then you'll need to paginate your records. This is achieved by making multiple API calls and crawling through "pages" of data. We support both page-based and keyset pagination. You can read more about that [here](https://docs.helius.dev/compression-and-das-api/digital-asset-standard-das-api/pagination). For most tokens, you can expect to have more than 1000 holders.

The `Get Token Accounts` method is useful for retrieving information about all token accounts for a specific mint or owner. You can use pagination with this method to fetch all the holders of a given SPL token. We have the [following example from our docs](https://docs.helius.dev/compression-and-das-api/digital-asset-standard-das-api/get-token-accounts#how-to-get-all-the-holders-of-an-spl-token), which uses page-based pagination to get all the holders of $BONK and writes their pubkey to a new file:

```
const url = `https://mainnet.helius-rpc.com/?api-key=<API-KEY>`;
const fs = require("fs");

const getTokenAccounts = async () => {
  const fetch = (await import("node-fetch")).default;
  let page = 1;
  let allOwners = new Set();

  while (true) {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        jsonrpc: "2.0",
        method: "getTokenAccounts",
        id: "helius-test",
        params: {
          page: page,
          limit: 1000,
          displayOptions: {},
          mint: "DezXAZ8z7PnrnRJjz3wXBoRgixCa6xjnB7YaB1pPB263",
        },
      }),
    });
    const data = await response.json();

    if (!data.result || data.result.token_accounts.length === 0) {
      console.log(`No more results. Total pages: ${page - 1}`);
      break;
    }
    console.log(`Processing results from page ${page}`);
    data.result.token_accounts.forEach((account) =>
      allOwners.add(account.owner)
    );
    page++;
  }

  fs.writeFileSync(
    "output.json",
    JSON.stringify(Array.from(allOwners), null, 2)
  );
};

getTokenAccounts();
```

If you have any additional questions, feel free to ask away here or in the [Helius Discord](https://discord.com/invite/6GXdee3gBj)!